# Реализация заполнения полей из json-файла в ajax-запросе при нажатии по ссылке

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Как написать ajax-запрос на заполнение полей json-данными

[image: скриншот]

JSON-файл

```
[
{
    "groupId":1,
    "groupName":"Семья",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"coldunox",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"fred",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"tom",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"jackson",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    }
    ]
},
{
    "groupId":2,
    "groupName":"Работа",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"west",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"cool_man",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"tedd",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"alisa",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    }
    ]
},
 {
    "groupId":3,
    "groupName":"Другие",
    "members":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "nick":"coldunox",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "nick":"coldunox",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
      {
        "id":3,
        "nick":"coldunox",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "nick":"coldunox",
        "firstname":"Павел",
        "lastname":"Широков",
        "email":"Paul_74128_14@mail.ru",
        "number":89053602244
    }
    ]
}
```

]

AJAX-запрос

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'GET', 
url: 'json_data.json', 
data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {   ?? }});
```

HTML-файл

```
<div id="contact_form" >
<ul >
    <li >
        <label for="fname">Имя:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  placeholder="Иван" />
    </li>
     <li>
        <label for="lname">Фамилия:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  placeholder="Иванов" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="mobile">Телефон:</label>
        <input class="input" type="text"  placeholder="89605402211"/>
    </li>

    <li id="last">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input  class="input" type="text" placeholder="ivan_ivanov@example.com"  />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: В файле несколько members, что именно нужно вывести в форму? Данные конкретного человека или данные всех людей?

Comment: Обычно это делается отдельным запросом для получения данных о пользователе, а не выбираются данные из такого json файла. Если нужно выбрать именно из такого файла, то сейчас напишу, но это будет не совсем правильно.

Comment: Конкретного человека

Comment: Уже добавил ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал цикл. Для нормальной работы добавь input'ам ID, а затем обращайся к ним в коде по их ID.

```
var needed_nickname = *сюда нужно ввести нужный нам ник*;
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'json_data.json', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {          
        for (var i in data) {
            for (var j in data[i].members) {
                if (data[i].members[j].nick == needed_nickname) {
                    $(*селектор input имени*).val(data[i].members[j].firstname);
                    $(*селектор input фамилии*).val(data[i].members[j].lastname);
                    $(*селектор input телефона*).val(data[i].members[j].phone);
                    $(*селектор input email*).val(data[i].members[j].email);
                    //выходим из цикла, мы нашли нужного пользователя
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

UPDATE: для события click на логин пользователя:

```
$(*селектор логина пользователя*).click(function(){
        var needed_nickname = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'json_data.json', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var a = 'coldunox';
            for (var i in data) {
                for (var j in data[i].members) {
                    if (data[i].members[j].nick == needed_nickname) {
                        console.log(data[i].members[j]);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: селектор input имени   --- вот так input[name='firstname'] ?

Comment: Да, можно таким образом. Удобнее будет добавить id и обращаться по #firstname, #lastname и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, выручили

Comment: Пожалуйста! Конечно, лучше бы сделать так, чтобы скрипт, генерирующий json, возвращал лишь 1 объект member, когда ему отправляют данные.

Comment: Alexxosipov, а как можно это сделать?

Comment: Сначала это поле должно быть пустым, а потом можно из списка выбрать нужный.

Comment: Такс...а json этот вообще откуда берется? Обычно json генерируется в back-end из запроса к БД, а затем уже поступает это все на front-end. Про поле - просто оставьте его пустым, затем при нажатии на пользователя оно будет заполняться

Comment: Приходится ведь самому прописывать имя пользователя,

Comment: var needed_nickname = 'fred';

Comment: Alexxosipov, это часть приложения

Comment: Добавил в конец ответа, проверьте.

Comment: Сейчас такой возможности нет, когда сделаю авторизацию, проверю

Comment: Тогда Вы точно не с того начали